# Left Join ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined error

Tags: sql, oracle, join

**Update: I switch LEFT JOIN to FULL JOIN and it works. 
However, I am too new to SQL coding to know why...so if anyone know, please let me know. Thank you!**

(I am using Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.0.2.15)
I don't know what I did wrong, but I can't make this Left Join works. If I use "Join" then it works. If I put "Left Join", I got error message of:

ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:
*Action:

The error is occur around the first left join

```
    Select fa.ABC 

    From AdminDisplay.AppointmentInfo fa  

    Left Join (  
    select info.feFpk as infoFpk  
    ,listagg(info.institution,'/ ') within group (order by rowid) as institution  
    ,listagg(info.fieldofstudy,'/ ') within group (order by rowid) as Undegradmajor  
    ,listagg(info.degreedesc,'/ ') within group (order by rowid) as Undergraddegree  

    from (select fe.ABC feFpk  
    ,fe.institution  
    ,fe.fieldofstudy  
    ,ld.degreedesc  
    from MasterDisplay.faceducation fe  
    join MasterDisplay.lkupdegree ld on ld.degreepk=fe.degreepk  
    where fe.educationtypepk in ('XXX')) info  

    group by info.feFpk  
    ) UG on UG.infoFpk=fa.ABC  
    ;
```

Comment: I'll make a guess and say that you need to be more specific in this attribute: rowid in `order by rowid`

Comment: One thing that would be very helpful (both for you and for anyone answering this question) is to cut down the SQL that you post by removing everything that is not essential for reproducing the error. For example is the commented out line needed to reproduce the error? What about removing one of the left joins? Or some columns? What is the bare minimum that will show the bug?

Comment: Sorry...the error happens in the first "left join". If I used "Join" instead, the whole query would works...it's just not the result I want.I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: This is totally unrelated, but if you use "with" instead of the inline subqueries, it really adds to the readability of the query.  I do find it really curious that changing an inner join to a left join causes this compilation error.  That doesn't compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure quite why switching from inner to outer join raises the error as it's coming from *within* the `UG` in-line view. Looks like it might be a parser bug, maybe.

You can avoid the outer-join error by just specifying which of the two tables in the `info` in-line view is providing the `rowid`, as @Amir sort-of suggested:

```
Left Join (  
select info.feFpk as infoFpk  
,listagg(info.institution,'/ ') within group (order by fe_rowid) as institution  
,listagg(info.fieldofstudy,'/ ') within group (order by fe_rowid) as Undegradmajor  
,listagg(info.degreedesc,'/ ') within group (order by fe_rowid) as Undergraddegree  

from (select fe.rowid fe_rowid
,fe.ABC feFpk  
,fe.institution  
,fe.fieldofstudy  
,ld.degreedesc  
from MasterDisplay.faceducation fe  
join MasterDisplay.lkupdegree ld on ld.degreepk=fe.degreepk  
where fe.educationtypepk in ('XXX')) info  

group by info.feFpk  
) UG
```

So in the in-line view I've added `fe.rowid fe_rowid` as an extra item in the select list; and then the `listagg()` calls are using that alias `fe_rowid` instead of the ambiguous `rowid`.

Using `rowid` to order anything is a bit strange as it doesn't really represent anything useful about the data. If you just picked that because you have to order by *something* then you could `order by null` which would also be indeterminate; or `order by feFpk` which might be slightly more useful even if it's a synthetic key.

Comment: It works! Thank you for the detailed explanation. I also tried ordering by fefPK :)